# Dynamically choose variable template based on branch trigger

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a folder structure as follows:

```
-> variables
    -> dev
       variables.yml
    -> pp
       variables.yml
```

I then have a azure-pipeline.yml that extends a pipeline template called template.yml. In my  template.yml, I want to use logic to determine which template variable file I want to use. So if my $(Build.SourceBranch) starts with fix/*, I want to use dev, or else use pp

Ideally, this logic would work, but does not because in azure pipeline at run time cannot do this:

```
- ${{ if or(StartsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/head/features/'),StartsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/head/fix/')) }}:
   - template: variables/dev/variables.yml
- ${{ else }}:
   - template: variables/pp/variables.yml
```

I'm not sure what to do at this point. I don't want to use parameters because the list would be too large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use "**heads**" in the branch name: "refs/**heads**/features", "refs/**heads**/fix".
2. Remove `/` at the last of the branch name if it doesn't have sub branch, eg: branch `features` but no `features/test1` branch.

The sample yaml:

```
trigger: 
 branches:
  include:
     - main
     - features
     - fix/*

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
- ${{ if or(StartsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/features'),StartsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/fix')) }}:
   - template: variables1/dev/variables.yml
- ${{ else }}:
   - template: variables1/pp/variables.yml

steps:
- script: |
   echo the SourceBranch is $(Build.SourceBranch)
   echo the testvar1 value is ${{ variables.testvar1 }}.
```

[image]

Comment: that's pretty cool, I always assumed parameters where the only thing that could be use to evaluate en so insert template stuff!